# Running praat on remote ubuntu server

Tags: audio, ssh, server, praat

I am working for a web application using praat features. I have written a script for that and it is working fine in ubuntu. But now i want to run these .praat scripts in a remote ubuntu server and I have already installed praat but when I run praat it gives me the following error:

> (praat:1364): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
>
> (praat:1364): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data:
>   assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion
>   'GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (praat:1364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion
>   'GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Please tell me way a that I can run a praat script in remote ubuntu server.

Answer (score 5):

When compiling Praat for use as a server for commands from your web pages, you may not need sound or a GUI. Do

```
cp makefiles/makefile.defs.linux.nogui ./makefile.defs
```

which creates the executable `praat_nogui`. If you don't need graphics (.e.g PNG files) either (i.e. you need only Praat's computation), you can create an even lighter edition:

```
cp makefiles/makefile.defs.linux.barren ./makefile.defs
```

which creates the executable `praat_barren`. Then type make to build the program. If your Unix isn’t Linux, you may have to edit the library names in the makefile.

Also you can download [praat6030_linux64nogui.tar.gz](https://github.com/praat/praat/releases/download/v6.0.30/praat6030_linux64nogui.tar.gz) or [praat6030_linux64barren.tar.gz](https://github.com/praat/praat/releases/download/v6.0.30/praat6030_linux64barren.tar.gz) from https://github.com/praat/praat/releases

[Praat](https://github.com/praat/praat)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and rebuilding praat from source using the makefile.defs.linuxs.pulse configuration solved it for me. I had to do some minor changes to get the build to work. You can find the modifications on [github](https://github.com/thias42/praat/tree/headless_linux_build).

Edit:
Using makefile definitions from makefile.defs.linux.barren now solves the issue.